# How to read contacts from addressbook in a tableview?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uikit

Anyone knows how to read all contacts from address book and show it in a tableview in the main screen ?

Comment: What language? Platform?  It sounds like you might be talking about Cocoa, but I can't be sure.

Comment: Additionally, you're tagging your question completely inappropriately.  Tags are not a method of restating the question.  They're to categorize the question - for example, if it is a Cocoa question, the Cocoa and Objective-C tags would apply.

Comment: Do you really need to pull the contacts into your own table view or do you want to use the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController?

Comment: yes i am talking about Cocoa.... iphoen application development...

Answer (score 0):

That is a very general question but you should start by looking at ABAddressBook which will allow you to retrieve address book records. It is [well documented by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone.pdf).

Then you can use this data to populate a UITableView with UITableView cells representing the records. Again, both of these classes are well documented by apple and here on stack overflow.